# How to completely convert one side of the detected edge into white?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have an RGB image (figure given) [Original RGB Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nIoi.jpg)on which I have applied Canny edge detection and have obtained the edges as in the figure
[After Canny Edge detection the edges obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah0j5.png)
Now I want to completely cover the upper half of the edge into white color. Something like this...[My Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEsmP.png). As it can be observed that the filling of white is not proper and many a time it goes below the edge line.

Code preferred in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some functions in opencv for this purpose but I wanna show my simple algorithm approach.

- Get canny output ( you already have it )
- Check every column of image until hitting a white pixel(255)
- When you hit a white pixel which should belong to circle mark it
- Make all column white until that marking pixel

Here is results and code:

Input:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Code:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    Mat img = imread("/ur/img/directory/img.png",0);
    imshow("Before", img);

    for(int i=0; i<img.rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<img.cols; j++)
        {
            if(img.at<uchar>(Point(j,i))>250)
            {
                for(int k=0; k<i; k++)
                {
                    img.at<uchar>(Point(j,k)) = 255;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    imshow("Result", img);

    waitKey(0);
}
```